# Making HTTP GET request from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, get, google-chrome-devtools

I have built a chrome extension and, at time of loading, I need to make a GET request to a server (trying it now from localhost).

Using Chrome debugger I can see that the call is made, but it is never received on the locahost server (which is running).

**Javascript code:**

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getInfo", { userId: "me" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert('Received!');
});
```

This is what I can see from Chrome debugger:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getInfo?userId=me
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Origin:chrome-extension://ginkmpnhbepolafnopjackbgefh
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
userId:me
```

If I put `http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getInfo?userId=me` directly on a browser it works well.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does your extension request [the right permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that the browser was blocking calls from the `HTTPS` site (where the plugin was displayed) to `HTTP://localhost`.

It started working when I deployed it to production with a `HTTPS` server URL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is problem in above code but same things I have done using below code via creating an AJAX `XMLHttpRequest` Object on chrome extension script.

```js
var userid="me";
var xmlHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new window.XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getInfo",true);
xmlHttpRequest.send("userid="+userid);
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
 {
  alert('Received!');
 }
}
```