# Making web requests to any url in a browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, browser-extension

I'm currently working on a browser extension but I'm having problems with web requests.

The extension needs to make requests to a self-hosted instance. That means that the url is different for everyone.

I'm having two problems with making the web requests (in javascript):

1. Just making any web request fails. See:

```js
fetch(`${base_url}/api/auth/status`)
.then(response => {
    // catch errors
    if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(response.status);
    };

    return;
});
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Results in the following two errors:

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

2. Reading articles, it looks like I need to add the exact url's to the manifest.json file that requests will be made to. However, requests are made to any url, because the server is self-hosted. So how am I going to fix that?

I've looked at these articles and SO posts, but none seem to help: [Dev](https://dev.to/qmenoret/browser-extension-secure-http-requests-from-content-scripts-2bdo), [Medium](https://medium.com/@chantlong/performing-http-https-requests-in-a-chrome-extension-ccba3367d2f8), [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164185/making-http-get-request-from-chrome-extension), [CSPlite](https://csplite.com/csp232/), [Csper](https://csper.io/blog/csp-violates-the-content-security-policy-directive), [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211359/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured both problems out.

The first problem, where JavaScript wouldn't run, was caused by the `action` attribute of a form. I had a form in my html, and using JavaScript, I set the `action` attribute to `javascript:login();`. This runs the login function inline, which is not allowed. I fixed it by changing the form to a div and adding an event listener to the submit button to run login.

The second problem was fixed by adding the following to the `manifest.json` file:

```
"host_permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/",
    "https://*/*"
]
```